# how to close all ionic 2 modals?

Tags: javascript, ionic2, angular2-template

I need to close all current **modal popups** and log out the user in ionic 2 application when the device goes to idle.

I used following methods to close popups in the home component.

```
this.viewController.dismiss().then(_ => {
  console.log("modal dismiss");
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

and

```
this.navController.popAll().then(_ => {
  console.log("modal dismiss");
}).catch(error => {
 console.log(error);
})
```

But it throws following error
***You can't remove all pages in the navigation stack. nav.pop() is probably called too many times.***

and does not close any popup. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewController.dismiss()` only closes the [current Modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/ViewController/). Meaning you will have to keep a reference to all open modals in and call `dismiss()` on each one.

You can set use `navController.setRoot(LoginPage)` ([link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)) to show the login-page.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it rather than forcefully setting a root page. Can we just dismiss all modals using some shared service or something like that? @robbannn

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public ionicApp: IonicApp){} 

  this.viewCtrl.dismiss().then(_=>{
  let activePortal = this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive()
  if (activePortal) {
    activePortal.dismiss(); //can use another .then here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a recursive function which takes a current active modal reference and dismiss that modal after that we will call on the that function again in dismiss() event. Here is the code ,

**recursive function**

```
public dismissAllModal () {
        let activeModal = this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive();
        if (activeModal) {
            activeModal.dismiss().then(() => {
                this.dismissAllModal()
            });
        }
    }
```

Call the function where we should remove all modals (I placed in login page in constructor)

```
this.viewCtrl.dismiss().then(_ => {
            this.dismissAllModal()
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I had the same issue and I solved it this way. The solution is to store all the modal instances using a service in an array. Then use a loop and dismiss all the modals refering them from that array.

**modal.html**

```
    <ion-button (click)="openModal()"> Open Modal <ion-button>
    <ion-button (click)="close()"> Close Modals <ion-button>
```

**modal.service.ts**

```
modalInst=[];
i=0;

storeModal(x)
{
       this.modalInst[this.i]=x;
       this.i++;
}
```

**modal.ts**

```
openModal()
{
    var modal = await this.viewCtrl.create({
    component: ModalPage
   });

 this.service.storeModal(modal);// storing modal instances in an array
   return await modal.present();
}

close()
    {
        for(var i=0; i< this.service.modalInst.length; i++)
         {
            this.service.modalInst[i].dismiss();
         }
    }
```

Comment: thanks man you saved my day.... the issue still happens with ionic 5 and  6 where Modal Controller create fires twice when clicked  but your solution really worked..